# 2-dimensional smooth lattice polytopes with minimal edge lengths

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

For each integer $k \geq 3$, does there exist a full-dimensional, $2$-dimensional, smooth lattice polytope $P$ with $k$ edges, such that each edge contains only two lattice points (i.e. only its vertices)?

More generally: if we are given a integers $a_1,\ldots,a_k \geq 2$, does there exist a full-dimensional, $2$-dimensional, smooth lattice polytope $P$ with $k$ edges, such that for each $i$, the $i$'th edge of $P$ (in cyclical order) contains precisely $a_i$ lattice points?

**Definition:** An $n$-dimensional, full-dimensional lattice polytope $P$ is called *smooth* if its normal fan $\Sigma_P$ is smooth. Equivalently, $P$ is smooth if for each vertex $v$, the set of vectors $\{v_E-v\}_{v \subseteq E}$ form a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-basis, where for each edge $E$ containing $v$, $v_E$ is the lattice point on the edge $E$ closest to $v$ (apart from $v$ itself).

Comment: Do you have an example of a smooth lattice heptagon whose edges are empty lattice polytopes (i.e., contain no lattice points other than their vertices)? The first appendix of Benjamin Lorenz's Diplomarbeit ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0514.pdf ) shows all smooth polygons with up to 12 lattice points. Since no 7-gon appears there, I'd look to the them as a counter-example to the first question.